# Installation of wifi drivers

Tags: 13.04

I use a toshiba satellite L755. how do I download and install wifi drivers. PLease I am new to ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Check out this [site](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi).

Answer (score 0):

Being new to Ubuntu :) here is the easiest way to detect and install the necessary driver.

1- Connect your Laptop to Internet using the ethernet port, then activate the detected driver (you will find it under **additional drivers** .

2- you may find some helpful print screens in the following article. http://itsfoss.com/install-additonal-drivers-in-ubuntu-13-04/

Comment: Thanks for replying. But nothing shows up under additional drivers. My old HD crashed and this is a new one. I installed windows 7, then ubuntu over it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this are the commands that I run when my Ubuntu doesn't know my wifi card:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: If this worked then please click on the check mark right in the left of my answer.